# Size single td in single row

Tags: css, html-table

I'm trying to size a single td in a table row.

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>
       <span>1</span>
     </td>
     <td marked="true"> <!-- Should be 80px height and width -->
       <span>2</span>
     </td>
     <td>
       <span>3</span>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now all my `td`'s have `60px` `height` and the `width` is set through js.

I want to set the `marked="true"` `td` to `80px` `height` and `width` and all other `td`'s should stay at `60px` `height`.

I'm able to resize the `marked="true"` `td` but the problem is, that all other `td`s `heights` are resized too and this should not happen.

I tried it with the `td` `height` and `width` attributes, with css and tried to size the `span`, but none of them work.

Is this somehow possible?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

This is how it looks like now:

It is a navigable days table.

[image]

The blue bordered `td` should be `80px` `height` and `width`.

And the others shoult be vertically aligned to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's best not to use a table.
Instead I would use something like the following HTML:

```
<div id="dayList">
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div data-marked="true">9</div>
    <div class="Weekend">10</div>
    <div class="Weekend">11</div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
#dayList {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}

#dayList > div {
    flex: 0 0 60px;
    margin:  1px;
    border:  1px solid #CCC;
    width: 60px;
    height:  60px;
    background-color: #EEE;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 60px;
}

#dayList > div.Weekend {
    background-color: #CCC;
}

#dayList > div[data-marked=true] {
    flex: 0 0 80px;
    border:  1px solid #00F;
    width: 80px;
    height:  80px;
    line-height: 80px;
}
```

It would look like this:

[image]

Comment: This is what I already did, the problem is, that all other td's get 80px height to and they should stay at 60px

Comment: Do you need to use a table? Could you send a reference image of how would you like the final appearance? I asked this why you could use a grid of "divs", for example.

Comment: I got it to work almost like @rinatoptimus answer, but it makes everything much more complicated. So I think you're right and I will remove the table. I'ts not the answer to the question but I'll accept it because this is what I end up with. thx

Comment: I believe there is no simple way using *table* , except with the use of additional *td* and *tr*,  and *rowspan* and *colspan*.

Depending on the final look, you may need to swap *nowrap* per *wrap*.

Comment: Yes this is how I did it (additional td etc..), but this is definitively not a clean approach.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to `td`.

```css
.big {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>1</span>
    </td>
    <td class="big" marked="true">
      <!-- Should be 80px height and width -->
      <span>1</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>1</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This resizes all other td's to 80px height, they should stay at 60px

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
 <td></td>
 <td rowspan="3" marked="true" class="marked" width="80" height="80">test</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
   <span>1</span>
 </td>
 <td>
   <span>1</span>
 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
td {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: Add  height="20" to <td> in the 1st & in the third <tr>

Comment: This is almost doing the trick, do you know if it's possible to use rowspan upwards, so one tr before and one after my main tr?

Comment: Don't understand clearly. Now there is one tr above & one tr beneath main tr. Do you mean that you want to add rowspan not to the 1st tr, but to the 2nd?

Comment: For now I have only one tr with my days in it, if i could add an empty tr before and after my actual tr and rowspan up and downwards, this would do the trick. but this is not possible see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817955/rowspan-upwards)

Comment: Well, it is impossible to add tr's before & after main tr, you're right. Unfortunately, it's difficult to find the decision without real example. Try to leave only main tr and add to the 1st and to the second td's these styles: border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
https://jsfiddle.net/rinatoptimus/4hw1a8f3/

Answer (score 0):

It seems this works as expected, added class .narrow:

```
.narrow {
  border-top: 25px solid transparent; 
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rinatoptimus/4hw1a8f3/

Comment: Looks like a simple way to solve it, but i need a 1px border

Comment: Try to add these styles to .qq span {
  padding: 10px;
    background-color: grey;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
https://jsfiddle.net/rinatoptimus/4hw1a8f3/2/